# Find out why an answer was deleted

Tags: support, deleted-answer

TL;DR: How to find out why an answer i wrote was deleted?

I wrote an answer to a question, got some comments and upvote and then the answer was deleted and i had no idea why. I raised a flag for moderator intervention, asked for an explanation  or that the answer would be undeleted, the flag was rejected and i didn't get any explanation why the answer was deleted.
Then i raised the moderator intervention flag again, asked again. This time i got a "...it didn't answer the question" answer. This is better, but i don't think this is correct.

What is the best way to find out why an answer is deleted, without raising 2 flags?

Semi Off-Topic:
To be fair, my answer contained a bit of information that was not directly asked but could help the OP to avoid the same problem in the future and my answer was a bit more complicated than yes or no, even the OP asked a yes or no question, but i gave an answer. Someone in the comments said it would not answer the question, i showed him in which part i gave an answer and asked why he thinks it is not an answer, didn't get a reaction back. However, i ask this question to get a general answer, not to ask about the deletion of this specific answer.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the best way to find out why an answer is deleted, without raising 2 flags?

If you have enough reputation, you can politely ask a moderator, in the [Ask a Super User Moderator](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114/ask-a-super-user-moderator) chatroom their thoughts on the reason any contribution was removed.

> How to find out why an answer i wrote was deleted?

You can ask a question on this website with enough detail for an explanation to be provided.  Those users with enough reputation, to vote to remove contributions, are typically active enough, to see a question like this.

However, based on the description provided, you have not identified the answer that was deleted.  **So it is not possible to explain the reason the answer was deleted, if you don't specify, which answer was deleted.**

If it was deleted then one of two things happened. Several community members voted to delete your answer or a moderator deleted your question. **In either case the most likely reason for the deletion of the answer is the fact, the community and/or a moderator, thought the quality of the answer was low enough to warrant the removal of the answer.**

> To be fair, my answer contained a bit of information that was not directly asked but could help the OP to avoid the same problem in the future and my answer was a bit more complicated than yes or no, even the OP asked a yes or no question, but i gave an answer.

Based on nothing but the description you have provided, it sounds like your answer contained unnecessary commentary, I vote to remove low quality answers that contained commentary daily.

Comment: Should not they simply be able to see that deleted post in "recently deleted" on their account page?

Comment: Sure; I don’t have access to that information; Author could easily provide that information.  I can see deleted answers.